# Scraping with Selenium and Python where pagination is involved

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to practice web scraping and have made a script that will go on to my personal Coursera site (I didn't see anything against this in their "robots.txt" file so figured it was ok since it is my own information). The main downside is that I still have to solve the CAPTCHAs when they pop up, but otherwise, it works in scraping text off of the first page. However, in my case I have multiple pages of text data to scrape and am running in to issues in figuring out how to involve pagination in the scenario. Does anyone have any suggestions? The problem method *I think* is my `def get_pages(self):` method. The print statement I put in it says that it got to 2 but it seems to terminate before actually running again...

The code is:

```
import time
import secret
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

'''
Code text
'''

template = 'Certificate Name: {}\nCredential ID: {}\n'

class CourseraScraper:
    '''
    Class variables
    '''
    def __init__ (self, url: str, username: str, password: str):
        # options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
        # options.add_argument('--headless')
        self.url = url
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.page_counter = 1
        self.selector_counter = 2

    def login(self):
        '''
        Using login info saved in secret.py, login using CSS_SELECTOR
        '''
        self.browser.get(self.url)
        print('Accessing browser URL...')
        username_css_selector = self.browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#email')
        username_css_selector.send_keys(self.username)
        print('Entering username...')
        
        pwd_css_selector = self.browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#password')
        pwd_css_selector.send_keys(self.password)
        print('Entering password...')
        
        login_button = self.browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[type="submit"]')
        login_button.click()
        print('Clicking login button...')
        time.sleep(60)
        print('Time delay for CAPTCHA...')


    def click_accomplishments(self):
        '''
        Once logged in, pause (there is a box element that sometimes obscures the
the drop down so the pause should allow the element to become visible) then click
"Accomplishments" from menu.
        '''
        print('Finding "Accomplishments" from drop-down...')
        select_dropdown = self.browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.cds-Avatar-initial')
        select_dropdown.click()

        print('Clicking link...')
        accomplishments_link = self.browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'li.dropdown-btn:nth-child(6) > a:nth-child(1)')
        accomplishments_link.click()
        
        time.sleep(5)


    def get_pages(self):
        '''
        This is the problem area - trying to select page, then scrape - but it does not proceed to the 2nd page.
        '''
        n = self.page_counter
        pages = self.browser.find_elements(By.XPATH, f'//*[@id="pagination_number_box_{n}"]')
        for page in pages:
            print(f'Starting on page {n}')
            self.scrape_page()
            n = self.counter_increment()
        print(f'Total pages scraped: {n}')
        print('Process complete!')


    def counter_increment(self):
        '''
        The page count is initialized to 1, then increment n to the next page(s) number
        '''
        self.page_counter += 1
        return self.page_counter


    def selector_increment(self):
        '''
        Box selector starts at n = 2, then increment for each one encountered
        '''
        self.selector_counter += 1
        return self.selector_counter


    def scrape_page(self):
        '''
        Scrape specific element using CSS_SELECTOR and return the text to the function write_text_to_file() to be written to .txt file.
        '''
        n = self.selector_counter
        
        while True:
            tag_css_selector = f'div.rc-AccomplishmentCard:nth-child({n}) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > a:nth-child(1)'
            try:
                accomplishment = self.browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, tag_css_selector)
                h3_text = accomplishment.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'h3').text
                to_field = accomplishment.get_attribute('to')
                to_field_text_split = to_field.rsplit('/', 1)[-1]

                formatted_text = template.format(h3_text, to_field_text_split)
                print(formatted_text)
                self.write_text_to_file(formatted_text)
                n = self.selector_increment()

            except NoSuchElementException as e:
                print(f'Reached end of elements.')
                break

            except Exception as e:
                print(f'An error occurred: {e}')
                break


    def write_text_to_file(self, write_text: str):
        '''
        Write values to file
        '''
        with open('div_elements.txt', 'a+') as f:
            f.write(write_text + '\n')


    def close(self):
        '''
        Close browser session.
        '''
        self.browser.close()
        print('All done!')



if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    '''
    Class calls
    '''
    url = secret.url
    username = secret.username
    password = secret.password

    browser_session = CourseraScraper(url, username, password)

    browser_session.login()

    browser_session.click_accomplishments()

    browser_session.get_pages()

    browser_session.close()
```

I have tried re-tooling the method using suggestions from ChatGPT but nothing has worked so far.

My expectation/desire is for the method to increment to page 2 (or further if there are multiple pages) and add the scraped data to the .txt file.

Answer (score -1):

General idea for scraping multiple pages with selenium is to use .click() method to navigate to the next page until the next page button is disabled.
You can use loop and try and except statement to break out of the loop when the next page button is disabled.
Example code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException, WebDriverException
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

link = 'https://www.ebay.com/b/TV-Video-Home-Audio-Electronics/32852/bn_1648392?rt=nc&_pgn=1'
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service((ChromeDriverManager().install())), options=options)
driver.get(link)

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//ol[@class='pagination__items']/li/a[@aria-current='page']")))

while True:
    try:
        # Searching for current page
        pno = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//ol[@class='pagination__items']/li/a[@aria-current='page']").get_attribute("textContent") 
        # Printing current page
        print("Page no: ", pno) 
        # Check if next page is not disabled
        driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='pagination__next icon-link']"))))
        # If next page not disabled, go to next page
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[@class='pagination__next icon-link']").click()
    except (WebDriverException, TimeoutException) as err:
        print("End")
        break
driver.quit()
```